# Import audio from persistentDataPath in Android with Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, audio, import

Thanks in advance to everybody.
I had a weird problem trying to reproduce audio files in Android devices. I use the same system for HL2 and it works.
I import audio files from the persistentDataPath and the .clip is found. I show the name and checked if it’s different to null and everything is good.The problem is when you want to play it nothing sounds.
I tested if the AudioSource has some type of priorisation conflict but when I added a clip manually it Works perfectly.
¿Does someone have any idea what could be the reason?

Here you can find the code:

//PART OF IMPORT AUDIO

```
private IEnumerator LoadAudioWAV(string Path, string audioName)
{
    WWW request = GetAudioFromFile(Path);
    yield return request;

    audioClip = request.GetAudioClip();
    audioClip.name = audioName;
    if (audioClip != null)
    {
        debug.text += audioClip.name;
    }
    SaveAudioFile();
}

[Obsolete]
private WWW GetAudioFromFile(string path)
{

    WWW request = new WWW(path);
    return request;
}

private void SaveAudioFile()
{
    audioSourcesToPlay.Add(audioClip);
}
```

//PART OF REPRODUCE

```
void Play()
{
    int indexList = audioSourcesToPlay.FindIndex(x => x.ToString().Contains(AudioName));

    if (indexList >= 0)
    {
        AudioToPlay.clip = audioSourcesToPlay[indexList];
        debug.text += "//" + "Playing " + AudioToPlay.clip.name + "//";
        AudioToPlay.Play();
    }

}
```

Comment: can you see if it is properly loading while in play mode?? I mean to check in inspector if audio source has refernce to clip when ever you run this function, just to make sure that the clip is changed or not.

Comment: Does `indexList` get set to a value above or equal to 0? What is `AudioToPlay`? Your clip is not null, but have you inspected it to see if it contains any data?

Answer (score 0):

Yes in the Editor there is a reference in the AudioSource to the clip  that should sound and it sounds. Then in an Android/IOS device nothing sounds and also it doesn't assign the .wav to the audiosource.

**AudioToPlay** is a list of audios and index is how I manage all the audios in different situations. I checked it out and It finds the audio file.

Thanks for your help ! :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).